# Ordered calling of the BAT-files

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Windows 7 x64.

Catalog contains `BAT`-files generated by `msbuild`. For example:

```
run-tests-in-autocad-2009-Gallio.bat
run-tests-in-autocad-2010-Gallio.bat
run-tests-in-autocad-2011-NUnit.bat
run-tests-in-autocad-2012-NUnit.bat
run-tests-in-autocad-2013-NUnit.bat
run-tests-in-autocad-2014-NUnit.bat
run-tests-in-autocad-2015-NUnit.bat
```

Now I need create the `BAT`-file (`run-all-tests.bat`), which will call each of that files. Warning: the order of calling is important! The name of each of `BAT`-file has the year value. Calls must to be sorted by that value. I want to write a cycle instead of hard pointing of each `BAT`-file name. The rigth ordering is difficult for me.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If the files are stored in a NTFS partition, they are enumerated in name order, so you can use something like

```dos
pushd "x:\where\files\are" && (
    for %%a in (*.bat) do call "%%a"
    popd
)
```

If it is not NTFS and files are not enumerated in name order, we need to force the order, and instead of directly request the file list, we execute a sorted `dir` command and process the output of it

```dos
pushd "x:\where\files\are" && (
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /on /b /a-d *.bat') do call "%%a"
    popd
)
```